# Safe Programming: safety of secret key

Tags: security

Given that somebody:

1. Knows "the approach your program takes to make information you don't want others to know what it is; that approach being a common way to do that most programmers use for this purpose; that approach being the currently best-known way to do this, known as "AES" in that other realm of things".
2. Can know the input and output of your program's operation (i.e. they know the exact bytes in your packet before your program has operated on the string).

Can the intruder derive your secret key?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic on Stack Overflow, because it is about cryptography, not programming. Such questions may be better suited for [crypto.se] Stack Exchange.

Comment: In fact, you may find [this question](http://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/1512/why-is-aes-resistant-to-known-plaintext-attacks) on [crypto.se] interesting.

Comment: Um, I'm a *programmer* and this problem is absolutely germane to my project, and is quite relevant to a broad array of *programming* projects. Topics overlap you know.

Comment: That said, the above discussion *does* answer my question. Thanks!

Comment: Seriously though, to say this is "off topic" is utterly idiotic. Programming deals with *algorithms* and all crypto involves algorithms. You guys need to get a life.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks very much to the above commenter for pointing out another [relevant discussion](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/1512/why-is-aes-resistant-to-known-plaintext-attacks) on a related site. It basically answers my question.

The tl;dr on that thread, to answer my question, is "no*". You're safe* if you use AES to encrypt something where attackers can know an example of the unencrypted text of an encrypted packet.

- (Insert standard crypto wonk's disclaimers about "no known attacks" bla bla bla but suffice it to say that nobody knows how to do it and we're all free to assume this about AES until we hear otherwise).

Answer (score 0):

This is called a [known-plaintext attack](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Known-plaintext_attack) and its success depends entirely on the encryption algorithm used. Obviously algorithms where the key (or other information) is not revealed in this case are usually better.

According to the linked Wikipedia article, AES is currently not known to be vulnerable to this type of attack. Emphasis on "currently", since crypto research is a hot topic.